# Expanding an element to fit window whilst in a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I really don't think the following is possible due to the nature of `ScrollViewer`s, but thought I'd ask anyway.

In the example I've mocked up, is it possible for the `Border` containing the `ListView` to expand to fill the dimensions occupied by the blue `Border` (visible when window is expanded) without losing the `ScrollViewer` applied directly on the `ListView`?

It is important that the `ListView` has a fixed height (at least on startup) for performance reasons.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Height="200" Background="Red"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Blue"></Border>
            <Border Height="200"  Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="50" Background="Yellow">
                    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                </ListView>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the final image is what you are aiming for then you might try:

```
            <Border Height="200" BorderThickness="0,10,0,10" Background="blue" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="50" Background="Yellow">
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
            </ListView>
            </Border>
```